# Remove \r from last of array value in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to remove \r from last of the array value.

```
var input = [ 'na\rme', 'phone\r' ];
 var  output = await input.map(function (value) {
 return value.replace(/^\\r/, '');
 });
 console.log(output)
Current Output:
[ 'na\rme', 'phone\r' ]
Expected Output:
[ 'na\rme', 'phone' ]
```

I am not able to get expected output. Please suggest script for the same

Comment: `^\\r` is beginning `\\r$` is end

Comment: You don't need to escape. Just `/\r$/` is sufficient. Also, why are you using `await` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Do not escape
2. Why await?
3. Use `\r$` (end) instead of `^\r` (begin)
4. or trim/trimEnd

**RegExp**

```js
var input = ['na\rme', 'phone\r'];
var output = input.map(val => val.replace(/\r$/, ''));

console.log(output)
```

**trim**

```js
var input = ['na\rme', 'phone\r'];
var output = input.map(val => val.trim());
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`trimEnd()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimEnd)

**Note:** This trims trailing spaces also

```js
var input = ['na\rme', 'phone\r'];
console.log(input)

var output = input.map(e => e.trimEnd());
console.log(output)
```